# How to recycle a bitmap in a AsyncTask? Android

Tags: android, bitmap, android-asynctask, recycle

I am writing a small android application that uses an asyncTask to display an image from a web service. The code works but it has been brought to my attention that I should recycle this bitmap.

My question is, is there a way to recycle this bitmap after I am done using it?

I attempted a solution using the onStop() and either the bitmap didn't get recycled or the image wouldn't display at all.

Here is my OnCreate

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Other unrelated things
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        imageUrl = bundle.getString("imageUrl");
        displayImage();
    }
```

And here is my AsyncTask

```
private void displayImage() {
        new AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>() {
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
                try {
                    return loadBitmap(params[0]);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Logger.e(TAG, getString(R.string.error_loading_image_bitmap));
                    return null;
                }
            }

            protected Bitmap loadBitmap(String urlSpec) throws IOException {
                InputStream is = new URL(urlSpec).openStream();
                try {
                    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                } finally {
                    is.close();
                } 
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
                if (bitmap != null) {
                    ImageView invoiceItemImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.some_id_here);
                    invoiceItemImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                }

            }

        }.execute(imageUrl);

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override method `View.onDetachedFromWindow()` and recycle your `Bitmap` there.